# Распаковка архива с паролем

Tags: архивация, setup, nsis

Создаю инсталлятор при помощи `NSIS`. Использую в своей программе библиотеку для удаленного управления, на которую постоянно ругается антивирус. Хочу поместить инсталлятор в запароленный архив, а во время установки его распаковывать. Как распаковывать запароленный архив?

Comment: Любой нормальный антивирус грохнет файл в момент записи на диск, толку ноль.

Comment: дело в том, что когда программа устанавливается, то антивирус на самом деле не ругается, он ругается когда скачиваешь его с интернета. А там он просто сканирует, докуда может добраться. А если будет запароленный архив, то он пропустит.